# hiding collections and sub collections in DSpace?

Tags: java, dspace

I'm using the dspace 5.5 in my repository. And I did a content restriction by restriction policy for some items to anonymous users. But when I do a search, it is displayed collections and sub-collections of restricted items. But when I access these collections the content is hidden. But I wanted you to hide all both the collections and sub-collections and bitstreams for anonymous users. Could someone suggest me some kind of setup?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to  assume you use Discovery for search, it's the default in DSpace 5.

What are the authorisation policies of the collections/communities that hold hidden items? If you make the collections/communities non-public (=no READ permission for the ANONYMOUS group), I believe this will be reflected in the search results when [Access rights awareness](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery#Discovery-AccessRightsAwareness) is turned on (which is the default). That is, they will be shown in search results when you're logged in as a user with READ access to the collections, but not otherwise.

You could also switch off having collections/communities included in search results altogether. There's a commented-out example in the [Discovery config file](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml) (link goes to 5.x version on github) that allows you to do that, see also the [DSpace documentation on Discovery](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery#Discovery-Defaultsettings):

```
<property name="defaultFilterQueries">
  <list>
    <!--Only find items-->
    <value>search.resourcetype:2</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you restrict a collection or community, DSpace will continue to provide a link to the collection or community.  When a user attempts to access the collection/community, they will asked to authenticate.

If you are using XMLUI, you can restrict the listing in your stylesheet.

```
<xsl:template 
    match="dri:reference[@url='/metadata/handle/10822/xxxxxx/mets.xml']"
    mode="summaryList"/>
```

It is not elegant, but it works.